# Which word describes getting stuck between two things?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Let's say I am closing a door, and my palm's skin gets stuck between the doors, and started bleeding. What word can I use to describe this situation?

Comment: Probably 'caught'. 'I caught my hand in the door', 'my skin got caught in the door' etc.

Comment: Pinched, trapped, squeezed

Answer (score 2):

For me (west coast USA), it's "I jammed my finger in the door". This seems to be common: Wikipedia has an article for ["Jammed Finger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jammed_finger) (warning: medical images of x-rays and swollen fingers, etc)

Google also attests to "caught", "pinched", "slammed" and "smashed" as being common.

Comment: I've lived in the western US for many years as well, but "jammed" has a different sense of meaning than "caught."  "Jammed" implies being driven forcibly.  A "jammed" finger would be equivalent to a "stubbed" toe.

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean the palm (wedging a little bit of skin from the palm between the door and the jamb), "pinched" is probably the best word.

> I accidentally pinched the skin of my palm in the door when I closed it.

Answer (score 0):

For more casual terms, I would recommend "I caught my finger in the door". Many doctors and professional places call it "smashed" or "jammed". All seem perfectly fine to me.

However, I might interpret "smashed" a bit differently, as it shows *extra force* made when you accidentally closed it on your palm/finger.

Do note that catching your palm in the door sounds a bit off, I would say "I caught/jammed my **hand**" instead of palm.